# Unable to login to bash after editing .bash_profile

Tags: 12.04, unity, bash, gnome-terminal

I've fiddled around with my `.profile` and `.bash_profile` to speed up some stuff:
`PATH=$PATH:/home/yoshi/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools`

First I appended the line to my `.profile` and perfect. Then I've read the comments:

```
> # This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
> # exists.
```

Good Idea! So I've moved it over there (had to create it). And that's how this trouble started. I edit via `nano`, closed file and terminal window. Started new window from the launcher and get a lonely cursor blinking on a blank screen. No typical `foo@bar:~$`.
Same problem when switching to a `tty` session.

Rebooting was possible and now I can login to a `tty` shell though it's staying blank first and I've to interrupt something (?) via `CTRL+C`. Sadly this magic doesn't work on unity's terminal. :(

The relevant part of my `.profile`. I've removed `.bash_profile`.

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I need an award for this.

Not knowing ubuntu also has a `.profile` by default I've edited `source .profile` to the end of `.bashrc`

`=> ∞`

Profile called bashrc, who called profile which called bashrc.... ...
*facepalm*

I managed to find this loop via logging execution of `.profile`. Adding well placed `echo "including X/finding Y"` revealed always the same pattern: `[...] echo "include .bashrc"` which brought me to mischievous `source .profile`-line :)

Comment: Now that's one i haven't seen. I know what i'm doing to my buddy for April fools day... *grins*